# Creating almost the exact same 2 plugs, but slightly different

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have my own plug module:

```
defmodule Module1 do

  def init(opts) do
    opts
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    # if some_condition1
    # something
  end

  # other stuff
end
```

And in router.ex

```
  pipeline :pipeline1 do
    plug(Module1)
  end

  scope "/scope", MyApp, as: :scope1 do
    pipe_through([:browser, :pipeline1])
    # .......
```

Now I want to create a second pipeline and scope using the same module Module1:

```
  pipeline :pipeline2 do
    plug(Module1)
  end

  scope "/scope2", MyApp, as: :scope2 do
    pipe_through([:browser, :pipeline2])
    # .......
```

However, if I were to create a second module, the difference would only be in this:

```
 def call(conn, _opts) do
    # if some_condition1 and some_condition2
    # something
  end
```

That is, I've only added "some_condition2", and everything else remains the same.

Now, how can I do that? Do I have to create the exact same module Module2 as Module1 and just sligtly change "call"? It'll result in code duplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the `opts` in Plug is meant for. You can pass it from your `plug` call and then use it inside `call`:

```
pipeline :pipeline1 do
  plug Module1, check_both: false
end

pipeline :pipeline2 do
  plug Module1, check_both: true
end
```

```
defmodule Module1 do
  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, opts) do
    if opts[:check_both] do
      # if some_condition1 and some_condition2 do something...
    else
      # if some_condition1 do something...
    end
  end
end
```

Now in `pipeline1`, `opts[:check_both]` will be false, and in `pipeline2`, it'll be true.

---

I'm passing a Keyword List here, but you can pass anything, even just a single `true` or `false` if that's enough (that should be a little bit faster than Keyword Lists as well).

You can also do some preprocessing with `opts` in `init/1`. Right now it just returns the initial value.